# Accessing Cloud SQL from local mysql client using cloud sql auth proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have a problem in connecting to my Cloud SQL - MySQL instance from local / gcloud shell. As per org policy we cannot have public IP for the mysql db instance. so I created a vpc network to use with this instance which created a private IP access only.

Now I am running [cloud sql auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy?_ga=2.162422908.-1128806156.1678114377&_gac=1.150195652.1704719459.CjwKCAiA1-6sBhAoEiwArqlGPpNIvtl_n_ztNQqr-31Alew_LWZHdsEL9W77UWxGSuAGLcSqwBXXmBoCFlcQAvD_BwE)  and trying to connect to this instance with mysql client on my local. But it stills fails with error
failed to connect to instance: Config error: instance does not have IP of type "PUBLIC"

Here is the connection test output:

```
./cloud-sql-proxy --run-connection-test --credentials-file <file> <instance connection name>
2024/01/08 22:13:03 Authorizing with the credentials file at “f”file
2024/01/08 22:13:04 [<instance connection name>] Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306
2024/01/08 22:13:04 The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!
2024/01/08 22:13:04 Connection test started
2024/01/08 22:13:04 Connection test failed
2024/01/08 22:13:04 The proxy has encountered a terminal error: Config error: instance does not have IP of type "PUBLIC" (connection name = "instance connection name")
```

Can you please help?

Comment: I wrote an article on that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a

And tell to your org admin team that the org policy is stupid.

Comment: With your current configuration, you can't. The preferred method is to use Cloud VPN and set up a site-to-site network. There are other options, as mentioned by Guillaume, that have performance, reliability, and cost implications. My suggestion, launch a Compute Engine instance and perform your tasks on that machine. Tip: I use WireGuard to link/network my local machines with my cloud systems. The end result is similar to setting up a VPN. I would get approval before using WireGuard because you can create security problems if you do not know what you are doing.

Comment: The use of WireGuard is pretty clever. Do you have a blog post describing how you put the pieces together?

Comment: @enocom - Yes partially. On my personal blog (https://jhanley.com) I wrote articles about WireGuard and Google Cloud. I should write a more comprehensive one to make this type of problem easier to solve. GCP + WireGuard is a great low-cost network solution. I don't need to launch a VPN and my GCP systems can talk to my local machines behind a NAT.

Answer (score 3):

Followed the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-private-ip to create a Compute Engine VM (the source) within the same VPC network where mySQL is running and access MySQL from there.